# custom module not working with custom bootstrap subtheme - Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I made a bootstrap subtheme 'mint', and in mint.libraries.yml :

**mint.libraries.yml**

[image]

Now this 'framework' styles are used in mint.info.yml :

**mint.info.yml**

[image]

Untill I was adding some other modules of drupal this theme was working.When I made my own custom module,error appears saying :

The specified library "mint/framework" does not exist.

Comment: please include your code, don't post images of code :)

Answer (score 1):

in your `mint.libraries.yml` file change `framework:` to  `global-styling:`
and remove below code from your mint.info.yml

```html
   libraries-extend:
bootstrap/framework:
-mint/framework
```

Answer (score 0):

The theme and module had the same name "mint" and therefore there were two files `mint.info.yml` in these two different folders. I guess they were conflicting. I renamed my module and now it works again.